# UI Text showing below GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a UI Text object at the bottom in my Canvas hierarchy, as I want it to render on top of everything.

However, the UI Text object (`MajorPrize`) is rendered below it's parent (`Blocks`).

How does this make sense?

My settings are below:

[image: Camera settings]
[image: Canvas settings]
[image: Panel settings]
[image: Hierachy]
My UI Text is behind the blocks where the red arrow is pointing: [image]

Comment: Did you have a custom material for the text?

Comment: No I do not, it's a standard unity `Text` UI object with no material. @shingo

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1171709/how-to-make-uitext-appear-above-sprites.html